# how to determine the lowest number in this curve

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

can someone help me on how to find the lowest value which the function will get ?

$y=\frac{1}{2}(e^x-e^{-x})+\frac{1}{2}n(e^x+e^{-x})$

thought of using t as $e^x$..but couldn't get an answer.

Comment: Is $n$ a constant?

Comment: $$2y=e^x(n+1)+e^{-x}(n-1)$$

If $n>1,2y\ge2\sqrt{e^x(n+1)\cdot e^{-x}(n-1)}$

Comment: n(>2) is constant

Comment: Have you studied derivatives ? If so,find the derivative of the function and equate it to zero

Comment: Assuming that $n$ is a constant, $y=f(x)$ and the lowest value will be the absolute minimum of the function. Find the critical points and then use higher derivative test to confirm the existence of minimum.

Comment: Setting $t=e^x$ sounds like an excellent idea. What do you mean by "couldn't get an answer"?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**. $$2y=e^x(n+1)+e^{-x}(n-1)\implies 2y'=(n+1)e^x -(n-1)e^{-x}$$
setting $y'=0 $ gives $$(n+1)e^{2x}=n-1$$ or $$e^{2x}={n-1\over n+1}$$
so $$e^x=\sqrt {n-1\over n+1}$$
and $$e^{-x}=\sqrt {n+1\over n-1}$$
putting these values in $y={1\over 2}\{e^x(n+1)+e^{-x}(n-1)\}$ we get 
$$y_{\min}=\sqrt{n^2 -1}$$
which is the same as lab bhattacharjee 's answer in comments (obtained by AM-GM inequality).

**Method 2**. It is known that if the product of two variables (say $x$,$y$) is a constant, i.e., $xy=c$ then $x+y$ is minimized at points for which $x=y$.  Here the product of $(n+1)e^x$ and $(n-1)e^{-x}$ is a constant. Therefore their sum is minimum at points for which $$(n+1)e^x=(n-1)e^{-x}$$ giving the same answer as method 1.